# fb:comments on touch devices

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile, touch, sencha-touch-2

I can not use the fb:comments feature with my mobile application because there is no native support for iframe scrolling on touch devices. Does anyone have a solution for this? I am trying to use fb:comments inside a Sencha Touch application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new attribute for mobile phone name 'mobile' ;)

(I personally didn't tried it yet)

You can find it at the bottom of the attributes section in the [official comments plugin documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

> **mobile** - (beta) whether to show mobile version. Default: false.

So all you need to do is to add **mobile="true"** or **mobile="1"** to your fb:comments tag like this:
`<fb:comments href="http://example.com" mobile="true"></fb:comments>`